# OpenType features for a math font in CONTEXT

Tags: math-mode, context, font-encodings, unicode-math, opentype

Using CONTEXT MkIV, is it possible to add custom/virtual OTF features to a font used in math mode?  Here is a simplified version of what I want to do.  I want to change all occurrences of `1.2` in math mode to `1/2`, that is, the period should change to forward slash when occurring between digits 1 and 2.  (My ultimate goal is to change period U+2E to U+66B when sandwiched between any two digits.)

Here is how I tried to achieve this.

```
\startluacode
digits = { 0x30, 0x31, 0x32, 0x33, 0x34, 0x35, 0x36, 0x37, 0x38, 0x39 }
replacements = { [0x2E] = { 0x2F } }
fonts.handlers.otf.addfeature {
  name = "mpf",
  type = "chainsubstitution",
  lookups = { {
    type = "multiple",
    data = replacements,
  } },
  data = {
    rules = {
      {
        current = { { 0x2E } },
        after   = { digits },
        before  = { digits },
        lookups = { 1 },
      }
    }
  }
}
\stopluacode

\definefontfeature[mathperiod][mpf=yes]

\starttypescript[math][xits][name]
\definefontsynonym[MathRoman][file:xits-math.otf][features=mathperiod,goodies=xits-math]
\stoptypescript

\setupbodyfont[xits]

\starttext
\startformula
  1.2.  %% does not work here
\stopformula
\addff{mathperiod}
1.2.    %% but works here
\stoptext
```

This does not work in math mode.  However, the same font feature works in text mode.

If I replace `mps=yes` with `ss08=yes`, I get the upright integral, showing that the list of features is indeed applied to the math font, and suggesting that the problem is that `mps` does not trigger for the sequence `1.2` in math mode.

Math fonts use an extended encoding, however, my investigation shows that the normal digits still occupy the range 0x30-0x39 and period has the code 0x2E (more precisely, `\Umathchar"0"0"002E`).  Is that correct?

I can guess that OpenType features are only applied in `mode=node`.  Adding this to the font feature definition not only does not solve the problem, but it also nullifies the upright integral feature.  (At this point I do not care much about the upright integral, but an additional question would be about how to get both `mode=base` and `mode=node` features working together.)

Comment: Imho you should better ask your question on the context mailing.

Comment: I did send the question there first, but have not gotten any response yet :(  I wanted to try my luck here as well...specially given that similar math font-related questions have been answered here before.

Comment: Perhaps Hans is in holiday. But imho you are right: math use mode=base and so it doesn't work. I have no idea what side-effects it would have to use mode=node instead, or if there is some way to get such substituations with base mode.

Comment: @MHB There is a lot of noise on the mailing list so some things just go unnoticed.  This is an interesting question though, so I think you should bump the thread or just ask the question again.

Comment: Are there any news here (did you receive an answer)?